# QT5: how to create .app bundle for macx

Tags: deployment, bundle, qt5, .app

I need to create a .app from my qt project for macx.
I've create a simple sample project console, with 
**CONFIG   += app_bundle**
in .pro file

then I used **macdeployqt**.

When double click on .app, the application start to blinking in the mac bottom bar for at least 1 minute, then stop it. No windows or message shown. When right click, only force quit command available.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Great: with a widget application works well, with a console application doesn't works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application uses libraries other than Qt, you need to copy the frameworks in `yourApplication.app/Contents/Frameworks/`

**Edit:** If your program is a console application, just create a shell script like this, put it in the same directory as your executable in app bundle, and modify your Info.plist so that this is the bundle's executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXECDIR=`dirname $0`
open /Applications/utilities/Terminal.app $EXECDIR/yourApp
```

Make the script executable by `chmod +x /path/to/the/script`. But I wouldn't make an app bundle for a terminal application. Deploy your application with an installer that installs necessary libraries to /usr/local/lib and your binary to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin

**Edit continued:** You can do it with a bash script run as root.

Hope this helps.